# Rename a column only if all its values satisfy a condition

Tags: r, function, dataframe, dplyr

I want to rename columns in my data based on whether all values in those columns satisfy a condition. For example, in a numeric column, if all values are greater than 5, rename the column to `large_values`, otherwise keep the column name as is. Another example, if all values in a character column are free from the `&` character, rename the column to `no_ampersand`.

### Data

```r
library(tibble)

df <- 
  tribble(~age_1, ~age_2, ~string_1,
        2, 7, "abc",
        3, 8, "efg",
        1, 11, "hi&",
        10, 6, "klmn",
        50, 100, "opq")
```

### Defining two functions for demonstration

1. Are vector elements greater than a value

```r
is_larger_than_val <- function(x, y) {
  all(x > y)
}
```

2. Do vector elements contain `&`?

```r
does_contain_ampersand <- function(x) {
  all(grepl("&", x))
}
```

### The question

So using those functions, how can I rename headers of `df` such that when

```r
is_larger_than_val(df$age_2, 5)

[1] TRUE
```

Will rename `age_2` to `large_values`, but otherwise in case when

```r
is_larger_than_val(df$age_1, 5)

[1] FALSE
```

will keep `age_1` as is?

And similarly, because

```r
does_contain_ampersand(df$string_1)

[1] FALSE
```

will keep `string_1` as is (but if it had been `TRUE` then `string_1` would have been renamed to `no_ampersand`)?

#### Desired Output

Given the current data, renaming based on the conditions I specified in `is_larger_than_val()` and `does_contain_ampersand()` should return:

```r
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  age_1 large_values string_1
  <dbl>        <dbl> <chr>   
1     2            7 abc     
2     3            8 efg     
3     1           11 hi&     
4    10            6 klmn    
5    50          100 opq
```

I'm sure this could be achieved with nesting some `if else` statements, but am wondering if there is a simpler way (maybe using `tidyverse` tricks?).

Thanks!

---

### EDIT

---

#### Putting the question in context

Following @Ian's comment below, here's the context for my problem.

1. I have an `R` data object that originates from a `JSON` file. Once I read the `JSON` file into `R`, it ends up in the following format:

```r
vec <- c(1, 2, 3)
names(vec) <- c("A", "B", "C")
my_data_object_as_list <- as.list(vec)

my_data_object_as_list
## $A
## [1] 1

## $B
## [1] 2

## $C
## [1] 3
```

2. I want to build a function that takes `my_data_object_as_list` and reorganizes it into a table.

```r
require(tidyr)
require(dplyr)
require(tidyselect)

organize_in_table <- function(as_list_object) {
    as_list_object %>%
    bind_rows() %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = tidyselect::everything())
}
```

```r
organize_in_table(my_data_object_as_list)

## # A tibble: 3 x 2
##   name  value
##   <chr> <dbl>
## 1 A         1
## 2 B         2
## 3 C         3
```

3. Because `organize_in_table()` is pretty generic, it returns a table with column names (`name` and `value`) that are not indicative to what each column is about. To address this problem, I want to add a `purpose` argument to `organize_in_table()`, and here is one example:

```r
organize_in_table <-
  function(as_list_object,
           purpose = NULL) {
    table <- as_list_object %>%
      bind_rows() %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = tidyselect::everything())
    
    if (is.null(purpose)) {
      return(table)
    } else if (purpose == "match_letters_and_numbers") {
      table <- rename(table, letters = name, numbers = value)
    }
    return(table)
  }
```

Now, `organize_in_table()` can return an object that has meaningful names:

```r
df_letters_and_numbers <- 
  organize_in_table(my_data_object_as_list, "match_letters_and_numbers")

> df_letters_and_numbers
## # A tibble: 3 x 2
##   letters numbers
##   <chr>     <dbl>
## 1 A             1
## 2 B             2
## 3 C             3
```

4. **Here I encounter a problem:** How do I know that `df_letters_and_numbers[1]` has been correctly named as `letters` whereas `df_letters_and_numbers[2]` is `numbers`? On what basis have I verified — when I renamed `table` within `organize_in_table()` — that the first column (`name`) is all letters and the second column (`value`) is all numbers? I didn't verify.

What if `my_data_object_as_list` had looked like this:

```r
vec_2 <- c("A", "B", "C")
names(vec_2) <- c(1, 2, 3)
my_data_object_as_list_2 <- as.list(vec_2)

> my_data_object_as_list_2 
## $`1`
## [1] "A"

## $`2`
## [1] "B"

## $`3`
## [1] "C"
```

Then if I would run `organize_in_table(my_data_object_as_list_2, "match_letters_and_numbers")` I will get the dataframe with mismatching column names:

```r
## # A tibble: 3 x 2
##   letters numbers
##   <chr>   <chr>  
## 1 1       A      
## 2 2       B      
## 3 3       C
```

### Bottom line

So my conclusion is that I have to condition the renaming step within `organize_in_table()`, based on the **content** of each column being renamed. To that end, I thought that the first step should be to define a separate function for each test I want to perform (e.g., are all values in the column numbers? are all values letters?). And because I want to make `organize_in_table()` as scalable as I can, I would like it accept any test that I can build a testing function for.

Comment: Can you explain what your actual ultimate goal is? It's hard to provide an answer that will be useful to you if we can't understand what the ultimate goal is. See [The XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/730130).

Comment: Thank you. I've edited the question to address your comment.

Comment: Pretty sure you could reduce this question to a single paragraph!

Comment: @geotheory, perhaps I could, but my original version was succinct and resulted in Ian's comment. So I provided more information for completeness. Feel free to edit the post if you'd like. My only goal is to be clear and allow people to help me solve the problem.

Comment: @Emman Fair enough I accept much of the length is the addition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sapply` on the data in order to create a logical index on the columns, but be careful with the character columns in the ampersand case:

```
i <- sapply(df, is_larger_than_val, y = 5)
names(df)[i] <- "large_values"

i <- sapply(df, does_contain_ampersand)
i <- i | !sapply(df, is.character)
names(df)[!i] <- "no_ampersand"

names(df)
#[1] "age_1"        "large_values" "no_ampersand"
```

Comment: Could you please explain the role of `|` in `i <- i | !sapply(df, is.character)`?

Comment: It's the vectorized logical OR, see `help('|')`.

Answer (score 2):

The `sapply` solution is great with it's simplicity. Here is an alternative solution with `data.table` that's a bit more effort. I think its the same principle but I've added a step to identify numeric and string columns to ensure only certain columns are being tested

```
# data.table solution
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)

# I think you need !(any()) rather than all
# This will identify if there is no_ampersand.
# Design tests so that if they are TRUE then change the column name for consistency
# Also & needs to be escaped with \\ to find it
no_ampersand <- function(x) {
  !any(grepl("\\&", x))
}

# function for taking data.table (dt), the test result and the new column names
# and updating the column name
alterColumnIfMatch <- function(dt, test_data, new_column="large_values"){
  # find ones to change
  alter_data <- names(test_data)[which(test_data == TRUE)]
  # if there are any, then use setnames to update to the new column value
  if(length(alter_data) > 0) setnames(dt, alter_data, new_column)
  return(dt)
}

# identify which columns to run through the tests
col_class <- sapply(dt, class)
numeric_cols <- names(col_class)[col_class == "numeric" | col_class == "integer"]
character_cols <- names(col_class)[col_class == "character" ]

# test for larger than 5 and update
test_larger <- dt[, lapply(.SD, function(col) is_larger_than_val(col, 5)),
                  .SDcols = numeric_cols]
dt <- alterColumnIfMatch(dt, test_larger, "large_values")

# test for no ampersand and update
test_ampersand <- dt[, lapply(.SD, function(col) does_contain_ampersand(col)),
                     .SDcols = character_cols]
dt <- alterColumnIfMatch(dt, test_ampersand, "no_ampersand")

# convert back to tibble for you
out <- as_tibble(dt)
out
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This does pretty much what I was looking for. This solution gives a wonderful framework, but unfortunately I have little experience with `data.table`. So I guess I'll simply have to convert this to `tidyverse` language.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. I'm the same way but the other way around! Merry Christmas :)